# No vertical mouse scrolling in version 11.3

Tags: notebooks

I am using Mathematica version 11.3 on Windows 10 and cannot scroll vertically through the text of a notebook using the mouse, the screen content simply is fixed. In Mathematica version 10 there is no such problem.

If I set the resolution (right hand bottom corner) to 75% scrolling is possible but reading is not properly.

Thanks in advance for helping me with this elementary problem.

Comment: Some info about the OS? Does vertical scrolling work ok with other programs?

Comment: Wolfram Support Is likely to be in a better position to help you troubleshoot your issue.

Comment: @Hans Olo Thanks for the question. Have added the information in the OP

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I have found a solution, see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I found out that scrolling is possible provided the notebook does not contain too long and too many groups of commands.

If I close most of the groups and leave only the group of the actual topic open vertical scrolling works fine.

Sorry for bothering you.